# Can't create/remove file in directory

Tags: linux, permissions

I created a directory with name `target` where I wanted all users of group `vaders` (I'm a member in that group) to iteratively read, write, delete, create files and folders.

I used the following commands to accomplish it:

```
umask 002;
chgrp vaders .;
chmod g+s .;
```

Now, another user from group vaders created a folder `new` and a file `trsu` in it. I, even with proper permissions (checked with ls -lah), was not able to delete that file or create another one under that `new` directory. I know that when I create, delete a file, I'm actually modifying that file's parent directory, but here the parent directory does have appropriate permissions.

[here's where I displayed permissions then tried creating and removing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uontm.png)

Note: SE linux is disabled.

Comment: Is selinux on ?

Comment: no, it's disabled: `SELinux status:                 disabled`